# Update to eregi() resulting from deprecation

Tags: php, preg-match, eregi

I have to update a line of code that is deprecated as a result of going from PHP 5.2.x to 5.3.x

The code line is:

```
if (eregi('Itemid=[0-9]+', $string) === false) {
```

Does anyone know what the new preg_match() arguments should be converted too?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( !preg_match( '/Itemid=[0-9]+/i', $string ) ) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !preg_match('/Itemid=[0-9]+/i', $string)) {
```

but maybe what is really needed is

```
if ( !preg_match('/^Itemid=[0-9]+$/i', trim($string))) {
```